# How to SUM an AS column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code...

```
SELECT WF.Word, WF.Frequency, WW.Weight, (WF.Frequency * WW.Weight) AS Product
FROM WF 
INNER JOIN WW ON WW.Word = WF.word
```

Which outputs the following...

```
WORD        | FREQUENCY | WEIGHT | PRODUCT
Fat           3           2        6
Ugly          2           4        8
Stupid        1           7        7
```

I also want to sum the product column at the same time. I understand how to sum an existing column but unsure how to sum a column i'm creating.

Comment: You're missing a `group by`.

Comment: What would be the desired result set?

Comment: What is shown above plus a seperate table with just a column called ProductSum which would have 21 in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(WF.Frequency * WW.Weight) AS Product
FROM WF 
INNER JOIN WW ON WW.Word = WF.word
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WF.Word, SUM(WF.Frequency) Frequency, SUM(WW.Weight) Weight, SUM(WF.Frequency * WW.Weight) AS Product
FROM WF 
INNER JOIN WW ON WW.Word = WF.word
GROUP BY WF.Word
;
SELECT SUM(WF.Frequency * WW.Weight) Product
FROM WF 
INNER JOIN 
WW ON WW.Word = WF.word
```